# Split string without removing the delemiter

Tags: php

I need to split a string using:

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s,&lt;&gt;123456789]+/", $message);
```

but if I do that I end up with the bare words from the `$message`.

Is there a way to split the `$message` without removing the delimiters?
For example: `"asd1 ,3" -> ["asd","1"," ",","3"]`

Comment: ---1: What prevented you from reading the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you look at [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) in the PHP manual, you'll see that can use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag with a capturing group:

```
preg_split("/([\s,<>123456789]+)/", $message, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```